# PhpStorm and BEM

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, bem

I can go from TSX via class to my SCSS.

[image: tsx]

I cannot do the same going back. I use PhpStorm and I miss the feature that VSC has. Preview of SCSS class all combined. It is difficult to know what class it is when nested deep in SCSS.

[image: scss]

Comment: In such cases it's better to submit a bug to WebStorm's bug-tracker providing a sample project: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB.

Answer (score 2):

Submitted to developers as [WEB-41364](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41364), please follow it for updates